DeepL API fails to translate from Turkish to Ukrainian/Russian
I am developing an audio translation application using Python and the DeepL API. The program successfully recognizes Turkish speech and transcribes it, but fails to translate the text to Ukrainian or Russian using DeepL
Here's the relevant part of my code:
from deep_translator import DeeplTranslator

class Translation:
    def __init__(self, logger, deepl_api_key):
        self.logger = logger
        self.deepl_translator = DeeplTranslator(api_key=deepl_api_key)

    def deepl_translate(self, text, dest_lang):
        try:
            lang_map = {'uk': 'UK', 'ru': 'RU', 'tr': 'TR'}
            deepl_lang = lang_map.get(dest_lang, dest_lang.upper())
            
            self.logger.info(f"Attempting translation with DeepL. Source: TR, Target: {deepl_lang}")
            translated = self.deepl_translator.translate(text, source_lang="TR", target_lang=deepl_lang)
            
            if translated == text:
                self.logger.warning("DeepL returned untranslated text. Attempting translation via intermediate language (English).")
                english_text = self.deepl_translator.translate(text, source_lang="TR", target_lang="EN-GB")
                translated = self.deepl_translator.translate(english_text, source_lang="EN-GB", target_lang=deepl_lang)
            
            if translated == text:
                self.logger.error("DeepL failed to translate the text even via an intermediate language.")
                return f"Error: DeepL did not translate the text. Original text: {text[:100]}..."
            
            self.logger.info(f"Successfully translated text (DeepL): {translated[:100]}...")
            return translated
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"DeepL translation error: {str(e)}")
            return f"DeepL translation error: {str(e)}"`

The DeepL API key is valid and the translator is successfully initialized. The supported languages include Ukrainian ('uk') and Russian ('ru')
I expected the DeepL API to translate the Turkish text into Ukrainian and Russian. However, it consistently fails to do so, returning the original text unchanged
I ve tried the following:
Direct translation from Turkish to Ukrainian/Russian.
Two-step translation: Turkish to English, then English to Ukrainian/Russian.
Not specifying the source language, allowing DeepL to auto-detect it.
Preprocessing the text to remove special characters and extra spaces.
I've also checked the DeepL documentation and confirmed that my API plan supports translation between these language pairs.
The log output shows:
2024-07-20 23:27:04,147 - AudioTranslator - INFO - Attempting translation with DeepL. Source: TR, Target: UK 2024-07-20 23:27:04,823 - AudioTranslator - WARNING - DeepL returned untranslated text. Attempting translation via intermediate language (English). 2024-07-20 23:27:05,970 - AudioTranslator - ERROR - DeepL failed to translate the text even via an intermediate language.
I am expecting the DeepL API to successfully translate the Turkish text to Ukrainian and Russian, or at least provide a more specific error message if there's an issue with the translation process.

Is the text parameter passed into the function a string?
Im very surprised that this if ever evaluates to true -
`translated = self.deepl_translator.translate(text, source_lang="TR", target_lang=deepl_lang)
        if translated == text:`

As you can see in the README, translated should be a TextResult, not a str, so you should compare translated.text with text. Also, you say turkish translation works, but in your example turkish is both the source and target language?
